# Use mox to mock a method called by__init__

Tags: python, mox

I'd like to stub out a single method in a class that is called by the **init** method.

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self): 
    # Some initializer code here
    ...
    self.method_with_side_effects()

  def method_with_side_effects(self):
    ... # Load files, etc.
```

According to the Mox documentation, you can mock a method by instantiating the object and then using the StubOutWithMock method. But in this case, I can't do that:

```
import mox
m = mox.Mox()
myobj = MyClass()
m.StubOutWithMock(myobj, "method_with_side_effects") # Too late!
```

Is there any other way to stub out that method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you subclass `MyClass` directly and override `method_with_side_effects`?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to stub out the method, you can use the stubout module:

```
import stubout

s = stubout.StubOutForTesting()
s.Set(MyClass, 'method_with_side_effects', lambda self: None)
```

If you actually want to mock the method, it's more complicated.  You can create an instance object directly with `__new__()` to avoid the side effects from `__init__()`, and use it to record the expected behavior:

```
import mox

m = mox.Mox()
m.StubOutWithMock(MyClass, 'method_with_side_effects')

instance = MyClass.__new__(MyClass)
instance.method_with_side_effects().AndReturn(None)

m.ReplayAll()
MyClass()
m.VerifyAll()
```

If you don't actually need behavior verification, using stubs instead of mocks is much less fragile.